# Django shopping cart update

Tags: django, cart

I am trying to send slg (as quanty when update shopping cart):

```html
{% for item in myCart.values %}
<tr>
<td class="product-col">
  <img src="/media/{{item.image}}" alt="">
  <div class="pc-title">
    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
    <p>${{item.price}}</p>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="quy-col">
  <div class="quantity">
      <div class="pro-qty">
        <input type="number" min="1" name="slg[{{item.id}}]" value="{{item.slg}}">
      </div>
              </div>
  </td>
  <td class="size-col"><h4>Size M</h4></td>
  <td class="total-col"><h4>${% widthratio item.price 1 item.slg %}</h4></td>
  <td class="total-col"><a href="{% url 'home:deleteCart' item.id %}">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my view, i am trying to get data form templates but it's not work

```html
def updateCart(request):
    slg = request.POST['slg']
  
    return render(request, 'home/check.html', {'myCart': slg})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the section about the way you submit the data. You might want to build a form
like below

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>

    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

and post the data so when you check the request.POST that it has some data in it.

With your code, I don't see any data being posted.